# JSON : true value come with quote

Tags: php, json, sencha-touch-2

I want to output a nested JSON array for my Sencha-Touch app, and I have to signalize the leaf nodes.

Heres is the right syntax :

```
  {
      "text": "Random",
      "leaf": true
  }
```

I create my array in PHP from server-side, here is the line where i'm adding the leaf info :

```
$myRow['leaf'] = 'true';
```

Unfortunately it's not that simple, the output, after json-encoding my array is :

```
{
    "text": "Random",
    "leaf":"true"
}
```

The quotes around **true** are problematic because Sencha Touch don't recognize the boolean value.

I tried without the quotes around **true** in my PHP file but then i get

> "leaf" : "1"

in the JSON callback...

I tried some other tricks but always the same issue.

Someone had the same problem ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://codepad.org/scPuzsFb, using a boolean works. Triple check your code.

Comment: Can you show us your json output code?

Comment: How are you converting the PHP structure to json ? Are you using json_encode or something else ?

Comment: Mhhh thank you felix, i find why i have the "leaf":"1" in output. 
I was doing utf8_encode() on my array, that's why it output "1" rather than true.

Comment: I can't answer my question because of my low reputation point (new member spotted ;-)) but : 

Actually it works with 
 $myRow['leaf'] = true;   
But I was using utf8_encode() so it changed the 
true into "1"

I've learn something, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works with

```
$myRow['leaf'] = true;
```

But I was using `utf8_encode()` so it changed the `true` into "1".

Answer (score 2):

Youre getting the `string` true becuse its a string in php... use a boolean

```
$myRow['leaf'] = true;
```

Comment: *"I tried without the quotes around true in my PHP file but then i get ..."*

Comment: looks like no one is catching that statement except you felix :-)

Comment: I am having the same issue any solutions so far??

Answer (score 0):

If I recall it's a bug in version of php < 5.2:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#107968

Simply try:

```
$jsonencodedstring = str_replace('"true"', 'true', $jsonencodedstring);
```

Comment: There is no bug (at least not what you mean). `json_decode` was only introduced in PHP 5.2.0 (some people might call it a bug that it did not exist before ;)).

Comment: Sorry, you are right... I found some of my own code... json_encode will always quote it... you can however do a replace on "true" to remove the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key){
    if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)) {
            $item = utf8_encode($item);
    }
});
```

Check the **if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true))** condition, that is the solution to above question asked, might help someone :)